# Replace long string in python code with string from a file (keep placeholders)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, file

I have to make a generator for some text files that must contain a long string with a number of differences from one file to another. I do this by having a DEFAULT_STRING with placeholders inside it. What I want to do is to put the text inside a file and keep the functionality (have the placeholders). Any suggestions?

```
DEFAULT_STRING = """A very long {ph1} string with multiple {ph2} ......
that keeps on going {ph3} and I don't like this big string 
inside my code""".format(ph1 = self._first, ph2 = self._second, ph3 = self._third)
```

The actual string 100+ lines, so it would be easier to work on a separate file containing just the string.

Comment: put it in a file, read it and use the string as a format template like if it was a literal. any problems with that?

Comment: so if I have "A very long {ph1}" inside a file, after I assigning to a string, will it recognize {ph1} as a placeholder and support .format?

Comment: yes, there's no magic. literal or file it makes no difference, {} are not special characters. try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can write your DEFAULT_STRING to a file as it is. When you want to use it to do any formatting, you would read the first line of that file and call format on that string just as in your example.

You can either replace the named placeholders in DEFAULT_STRING with positional ones (e.g. {0}, {1}) or you can parse the names from the string by looking for characters between "{" and "}" and build a **kwargs dictionary to pass into .format() using the names as keys and values as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = dict(ph1 = self._first, ph2 = self._second, ph3 = self._third)

with open('long_string.txt') as infile:
  with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(infile.read().format(**values))
```